# How to fix CpResource error not found | React Native

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native

I'm using React Native with Visual Studio IDE.

Previously I installed [native base](https://www.npmjs.com/package/native-base) using npm. Now I uninstalled that npm also removed my all my dependency code in project. I did `pod install` and `npx react-native run-ios`. I got Build Failed error.

I'm getting error on `project.pbxproj` file

**Error:**
[image]